# Is there a workaround for defining a unique constraint that treats NULL values as non-distinct?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to define a unique constraint in MySQL that will treat NULLs as non-distinct to each other.

I.e.
If I have a table like this:

```
column1 int(11) NOT NULL,
column2 int(11) DEFAULT NULL
```

whose values are populated by AUTO INCREMENT INT, and then define a unique constraint as follows:

```
UNIQUE KEY uniq1 (column1, column2),
```

I can insert (1, NULL) multiple times because of MySQLs behaviour to treat NULLs as distinct to each other in a unique constraint. If however I actually wanted to prevent such duplicate insertion, is there a way other than assigning a magic value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented under [`CREATE INDEX` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-index.html):

> For all engines, a `UNIQUE` index permits multiple `NULL` values for columns that can contain `NULL`.

You cannot define an index over an expression (such as given in your question), therefore MySQL's `UNIQUE` indexes cannot enforce the constraint as you wish.

Instead, you can create a `BEFORE INSERT` [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) that raises an error if a matching record already exists:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER uniq1 BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
  IF EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM   my_table
    WHERE  column1 <=> NEW.column1 AND column2 <=> NEW.column2
    LIMIT  1
  ) THEN
    SIGNAL
      SQLSTATE '23000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Duplicate entry for key uniq1';
  END IF;;
```

To prevent `UPDATE`s from causing a similar problem, you will probably want to create a similar `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger too.

Comment: thanks, if I wanted to NOT permit multiple NULLs though, is there a way?