# Treating `null` as a distinct value in a table unique constraint

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table which I use to define default and custom options for a client. If the `custom_id` field has a value then it represents a record for a unique custom job. If it is empty then the record represents the default option for the client.

My issue is that I would like to enforce uniqueness in two situations:

1. `custom_id`, `client` and `option` are all non-null
2. `client` and `option` are non-null, but `custom_id` is null

The table definition below works in the first case, but not in the second, since null is not treated as a value. Is there a way to make it so that null is treated as a value?

```
class OptionTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "option_table"
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint("custom", "client", "option", name="uix_custom_client_option"),
    )

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    custom_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("custom.id"), nullable=True)
    client = Column(String, nullable=False)
    option = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

Here is some sample data and the result when they are added in order:

```
+----+----------+----------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
| id | CustomID |  Client  | Option |                   result                    |
+----+----------+----------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 123      | MegaCorp | Apple  | OK                                          |
|  2 | 123      | MegaCorp | Apple  | not unique                                  |
|  3 | NULL     | MegaCorp | Apple  | OK                                          |
|  4 | NULL     | MegaCorp | Google | OK                                          |
|  5 | NULL     | MegaCorp | Google | this one should fail, but currently doesn't |
+----+----------+----------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
```

This [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17681765/1706564) does what I'm looking for, using MySQL. The ideal solution would be to do this using sqlalchemy.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) suggests this is standard SQL behavior; NULL cannot violate a uniqueness constraint. You need a real value to indicate the lack of a custom ID.

Comment: @chepner Yes, this is absolutely standard SQL behaviour. I'm asking if there is a way to get around it using sqlalchemy

Comment: There is a related question which has before insert and before update statements for MySQL which achieve what I'm looking for. Added to the question.

Comment: The problem is that your database itself (to which SQLAlchemy is just an interface) allows row 5. I'd suggest using a non-nullable Boolean-valued "has_custom" column instead of the custom ID itself in the uniqueness constraint. (Of course, then the problem becomes preventing a record from having a True/Null combination of the two columns.)

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the pointers. I've found a solution using partial indexes. I'll add an answer once I have it worked up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the approach recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8289253/1706564), the solution is to create two [partial indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html).

Using sqlalchemy for the example in the question, this looks like:

```
class OptionTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "option_table"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    custom_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("custom.id"), nullable=True)
    client = Column(String, nullable=False)
    option = Column(String, nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        Index(
            "uix_custom_client_option", 
            "custom_id", 
            "client", 
            "option", 
            unique=True, 
            postgresql_where=custom_id.isnot(None)
        ),
        Index(
            "uix_client_option", 
            "client",  
            "option", 
            unique=True, 
            postgresql_where=custom_id.is_(None)
        ),
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

I've made a custom compiler argument for `NULLS NOT DISTINCT`

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint


UniqueConstraint.argument_for("postgresql", 'nulls_not_distinct', None)


@compiles(UniqueConstraint, "postgresql")
def compile_create_uc(create, compiler, **kw):
    """Add NULLS NOT DISTINCT if its in args."""
    stmt = compiler.visit_unique_constraint(create, **kw)
    postgresql_opts = create.dialect_options["postgresql"]

    if postgresql_opts.get("nulls_not_distinct"):
        return stmt.rstrip().replace("UNIQUE (", "UNIQUE NULLS NOT DISTINCT (")
    return stmt


class OptionTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "option_table"
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint(
            "custom", "client", "option", 
            postgresql_nulls_not_distinct=True,  # here it is.
            name="uix_custom_client_option"),
    )
```

Note that Alembic handles it well.
Try yourself `alembic upgrade head --sql`

Comment: this doesn't seem to generate the expected alembic sql. i am getting the same alembic version command, sql as before

Comment: Alembic added this feature in this August, it seems: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/pull/1249. Try to update it to 1.12.x or later, and check if this flag is in your migration file. It looks like alembic not triggering custom compilers, somehow, it uses its own compiler, which ignores default sqlalchemy when running migration.

Answer (score 2):

I would do

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON atable
   (client, option, coalesce(custom_id, -42));
```

where `-42` is a value that cannot occur for `custom_id`.

How does it work?

If there are two rows with identical `client`, `option` and `custom_id`, all of which are `NOT NULL`, it will work just like a regular unique index and will prevent the second row from being added.

If there are two rows with identical `client` and `option` that both have `custom_id IS NULL`, then the index will prevent the second row from being added, because it indexes `-42` instead of `NULL`, and the two index tuples would be identical.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make it so that null is treated as a value?

Since **Postgres 15**, there is a way with the added clause **`NULLS NOT DISTINCT`**. Your index can now be:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uix_custom_client_option ON test_table(custom, client, option) NULLS NOT DISTINCT;
```

To note: `null` is treated as a value (that conflicts with another `null`) in all index columns of the same index this way, not just in `option`. But that's not effective anyway while `custom` and `client` are defined `NOT NULL`.
Details:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)