# Flask-SQLAlchemy create multi-column UniqueConstraint with multiple nullable columns

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a model in my flask project:

```
class Location(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'location'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    longitude = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    latitude = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    address_1 = db.Column(db.String(50))
    address_2 = db.Column(db.String(8))
    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id', ondelete='SET NULL'))
    city_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('city.id', ondelete='SET NULL'))
```

I need to ensure uniqueness of location via applying unique constraint on all columns except an `id`. I've tried this one:

```
__table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint(
            longitude,
            latitude,
            address_1,
            address_2,
            country_id,
            city_id,
            name="unique_loc"),
    )
```

... but I still can save duplicates because of nullable `address_1', 'address_2' ([in more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646553/treating-null-as-a-distinct-value-in-a-table-unique-constraint)). I've investigated a bit and found a possible [solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299098/why-doesnt-my-unique-constraint-trigger/299107#299107):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_loc ON location
(longitude, latitude, COALESCE(address_1, ''), COALESCE(address_2, ''), country_id, city_id);
```

Is it possible to write this constraint either via ORM or raw query? The database I use - postgres 13. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found out how to create an index with raw query. All you need is generate new migration with `flask db migrate` and modify both `def upgrade()` and 'def downgrade`:

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    ...
    op.execute(f"CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_loc ON location "
               f"(longitude, latitude, COALESCE(address_1, '-1'), "
               f"COALESCE(address_2, '-1'), country_id, city_id);")
    ...
    # ### end Alembic commands ###

def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    ...
    op.drop_index('unique_loc', table_name='location')
    ...
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Index` (with `unique=True` option) and `func.coalesce`:

```py
   from sqlalchemy import func
   ...   

   __table_args__ = (
        db.Index(
            "unique_loc",
            longitude,
            latitude,
            func.coalesce(address_1, ''),
            func.coalesce(address_2, ''),
            country_id,
            city_id,
            unique=True
        ),
    )
```

Comment: I've ran `flask db migrate` and got an error `UserWarning: autogenerate skipping functional index unique_loc; not supported by SQLAlchemy reflection`. However, I've found solution with raw query thanks to your response. Thanks for your help.